# AnySoftKeyboard: Integrate language pack into apk without having to use addon

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-keypad

I want to fork the AnySoft keyboard and add a language pack to it for deployment as a standalone apk. It has a way of adding language as a language pack that has to be installed separately by the user. I want to integrate the language pack to standalone apk. Can this be achieved and if yes, how?
Source Code for Keyboard:
https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard
Language Pack:
https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/LanguagePack

Answer (score 2):

I found out that it was rather easier thing to do than what I perceived.
The github repository for AnySoftKeyboard contains English Language Pack by defualt which s in compiled form. So we can add/replace our language pack by compiling it first and adding to AnySoftKeyboard cloned repository.

Comment: I created an android keyboard based on AnySoftKeyboard. I have now a lot of experience with it. If you feel like you need my help with it someday. You can send me a message on my twitter account. You will find a link to that on my profile.

Comment: Hello @Zubair Zahoor, did you successfully replaced the default English keyboard from the main (ime) apk, and integrated another one as default?